# Theorem of a minimal polynomial vector

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

***Theorem: Minimal polynomial for a vector $v\in \text{(Complex numbers without 0 )}^n$ on a matrix A divides the minimal polynomial of a matrix A.***

Above should be a theorem from linear algebra. However it does not make sense to me what it actually means.

So my question is: what does "vector" in the context above mean?

I also searched online and I could not find any similar theorem.

Comment: The minimal polynomial for a matrix $A$ relative to a vector $v$ is the (monic) polynomial of minimal degree $p$ such that $p(A)v=0$.

Comment: I see so this vector is actually an eigenvector @Quimey

Comment: No, it could be any vector, the eigenvectors are exactly the vectors such that the (relative) minimal polynomial has degree 1.

Comment: @VLC For example, consider the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1}
$$
and the vector $v = (1,0,0)$. The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(x-1)(x^2 + 1)$, but the minimal polynomial of $v$ on $A$ is $x^2 + 1$. Note that $v$ is not an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: @VLC The fact that the entries of the vector are non-zero is not actually essential, but for the sake of matching the hypothesis of the theorem as you have written it: take
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}, \quad v = \pmatrix{2\\-1\\-1}.
$$
The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$, and the minimal polynomial of $v$ on $A$ is $x^2 + x + 1$. Again, $v$ is not an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: @VLC The key point here is that there is nothing "special" about the particular vector $v$ for the purposes of the theorem. If you're looking for an "interesting" vector here, then we can say the following. "Most of the time", the minimal polynomial of $v$ on $A$ will be the same as the minimal polynomial of $A$ (which is allowed for by the theorem since every polynomial divides itself), so arguably the vectors for which the minimal polynomial of $A$ on $v$ is distinct from that of $A$ are special.

Comment: @BenGrossmann What does actually $v$ on $A$ mean, I know it doesn't mean that we multiply the matrix by the vector, so what does it mean.

Comment: @VLC "$v$ on $A$" does not mean anything by itself. **The minimal polynomial of** $v$ on $A$ has the definition that Quimey explained in his comment

Comment: @BenGrossmann I know how to get the minimal polynomial of a matrix $A$. But what is the process of getting the minimal polynomial of matrix $A$ relative to a vector $v$ ?

Comment: @VLC I don't know of any standard algorithm for doing so. However, one approach to doing so is to use either the Jordan form or rational canonical form of $A$.